# Understanding Question Closure on Stack Overflow: A Concern and Feedback on Current Community Policies

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I recently posted a question about implementing reusable background services in Flutter for Android and iOS. However, it was closed with the reason *"This question needs to be more focused."* I'm struggling to understand why it was deemed unfocused, as I believe my question is specific, detailed, and related to a programming problem.

Here's the question I asked:
[my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346801/implementing-reusable-background-services-in-flutter-for-android-and-ios)

It's astounding to witness simple questions, such as "What and where are the stack and heap?"—answers to which can be readily found in basic documentation—accumulate +9k upvotes.

In contrast, questions that demand a thorough analysis or require specific guidance often meet with unexplained downvotes. This is not just discouraging—it fundamentally undermines the purpose of a knowledge-sharing platform like Stack Overflow.

The community policies governing such responses are, in my view, in dire need of reassessment and reform ASAP.

Comment: [response to rev. 3]: That simple questions get large numbers of upvotes is just part of human nature and how gaining knowledge works. A **lot** more people will A) have those questions, because the question is simple and/or early in the learning process, and B) dramatically more people will know that an answer is correct or be helped by the answer. Such answers are usually easy to verify, so this further contributes to people knowing that the answer is correct. Thus, for the first such question asked, the questions and their answers naturally end up with large numbers of upvotes over time.

Comment: Long, involved and/or esoteric questions and answers tend to get *far* fewer people viewing them and take substantially more time and effort to understand the question and judge the correctness/accuracy of each answer. People tend not to put in that time. It can also be that many of the people viewing that Q&A don't have the subject matter expertise to evaluate the quality of the posts. Thus, those posts *tend* to have lower scores.

Comment: Your question is way too broad and was quite rightly closed.

Comment: @Makyen 
the voting dynamics on Stack Overflow are fundamentally flawed. Based on what you are saying Votes seem to reflect emotional resonance rather than the intrinsic value of a question. It's problematic that questions easily answered by consulting documentation are encouraged—it disincentivizes preliminary research, encouraging developers to forego research before posting their questions. These practices undermine the true purpose of Stack Overflow. This needs immediate attention.

Comment: @JK I must express concern over the non-constructive nature of your response. Upon revisiting your answer, I struggle to find any substantive information, leading me to believe that the comments section would be cleaner and more focused without such interventions. Furthermore, I find it disconcerting that users are endorsing your answer with upvotes, as it does not promote the knowledge sharing this platform is intended for. Based on the upvotes, it appears that non-constructive content is being rewarded more than meaningful contributions, which is a worrisome trend for the community.

Comment: You're welcome to make proposals, but the primary goal of the site is ["to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every [on topic] question about programming"](//stackoverflow.com/tour). That includes easy questions, even ones which could easily be looked up in the documentation. If you, or anyone, feels a question is so simple as to not be useful or lacks research effort (such as not doing an easy search in the documentation), then the appropriate response is downvoting, as the tooltip for the downvote button says. But, many simple questions actually are useful to many people.

Comment: I appreciate your perspective, @Makyen, and understand the importance of building a library of high-quality answers to every programming question. However, I believe that the voting dynamics on Stack Overflow could benefit from reassessment.
As it stands, the system seems to reward simplicity and emotional resonance over the intrinsic value of a question. This creates a situation where questions that could be easily answered by referencing documentation are not only allowed but encouraged, leading to a devaluation of preliminary research.

Comment: While I agree that even simple questions can be beneficial to many, it's also important to maintain a balance that respects and rewards the time and effort put into more complex, researched questions.
The current system, in my opinion, risks discouraging such efforts and might deter contributors who seek to engage in deeper discussions and analyses.

Comment: As I said, @DavitJanashia, you're welcome to make proposals as to possible ways to change things. However, prior to making a proposal, I strongly recommend researching the various proposals which have previously been made (here on MSO and on Meta Stack Exchange) and the responses they received, both from the community and from the company. Doing such research is likely to result in any proposal being received better than if it comes at the situation cold.

Comment: @Makyen I believe there's been some misunderstanding. I'm not currently making a proposal for changes to Stack Overflow. Instead, I am expressing my feedback and concern about the existing voting dynamics. This, in my opinion, seems to value simplicity and emotional resonance more than the intrinsic merit of a question, which is a concern that should be addressed. I hope this clarification makes my intentions clear.

Comment: I read @Makyen's comments as suggesting, not that you are currently making a specific proposal, but that you do want to see change, and that one way to effect such change would be to make such a proposal.  In that vein, they are advising you how to avoid some of the problems that have befallen users making such proposals in the past, should you wish to make such a proposal.

Comment: @Davit you are wrong.  The scope of your question is too large, and you are asking for opinions.  Broad questions and opinion questions are simply not allowed here.  Read the rules. You are concentrating on how well you wrote the question, how good your explanation is etc. But those factors simply don't matter because we do not allow that type of question.   You could write the best question ever asked in all of history, but if it is opinion based then it will be closed.  My short comment "too broad, should be closed" is therefore 100% correct and does not need any more detail.

Comment: @JK, your response is unfortunately symptomatic of a troubling trend I've noticed on Stack Overflow - the reduction of meaningful dialogue to dismissive one-liners. Your assertion 'Your question is way too broad and was quite rightly closed' brings nothing of value to this discussion, serving only to stifle inquiry and preclude deeper understanding. This isn't about my question alone; it's about the core values of this platform, which is to encourage the sharing of knowledge, not discourage it with hollow rebuttals. In my view, your approach goes against everything this community stands for.

Comment: @JK. I have a truly marvelous presentation of a question which this site is too narrow-minded to contain.

Comment: @Makyen, I appreciate your suggestions and the gravity of considering a proposal hasn't escaped my attention. Having given it due thought, I realize the importance and urgency of addressing the voting dynamics issue on Stack Overflow. However, I also understand the complexity of this problem. It calls for an in-depth exploration of the platform, careful data gathering, and understanding the intricacies of user behavior.

Comment: Moreover, the situation seems to transcend the voting system. It's a multi-dimensional issue that might require a series of interconnected proposals rather than just one, each finely tuned to work cohesively within the larger system. So, before I can confidently propose a comprehensive solution, there's a considerable amount of study needed on my part to grasp the platform's inner workings and dynamics in their entirety.

Comment: @RyanM, thanks for clarifying Makyen's comments.

Comment: There isn't an actual question in it (the closest is *"I'm looking for advice on how to implement this functionality"*). It is better to keep to form.

Comment: "The community policies governing such responses are, in my view, in dire need of reassessment and reform ASAP." - perhaps but saying that won't change a thing. No ideas is no advancement. The only use this meta post has is you venting your frustration.

Comment: @Gimby I agree that concrete ideas are needed to facilitate change. However, raising awareness about an issue that impacts the community is a vital first step. I assure you, this post is not just about venting frustration; it is an effort to initiate a discussion on a matter. Furthermore, I've already taken action and am working on developing a more focused discourse that delves deeper into the complexities of the current situation.

Answer (score 26):

> I'm looking for advice on how to implement this functionality specifically for Android and iOS platforms using Flutter.

We don't do advice on Stack Overflow. Ask 10 "experts" and they will advise 10 different things and in 6 months 4 different experts added 6 new ways to implement this. It will never end.

Instead, you could ask about a specific obstacle you encounter when you implement one of the features of your app for all target devices. That specific obstacle is likely to have a limited number of ways to get solved. That answer will guide you on how to implement the specific feature and the next feature.

In some cases, where you really have a software engineering question and not a programming one, you might look at other sites in the SE network. One such site is [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but keep in mind that their policy on what an on-topic question is, is often more strict than here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: With all due respect, I would argue Stack Overflow does frequently present advice. In our current structure, it may be that advice alone is not necessarily accepted as proper, but it wasn't always that way. Opinion based posts which are rooted in expert experience are supposed to be supported here, and if 10 experts give 10 different approaches, then voting from the community is supposed to sort that out. Isn't that the design? I feel like that a huge swath of content creation is being blocked by not allowing these situations to play out, and that our creation metrics are hampered as a result.